# How to set up AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am hoping to create a multi-player game using AndEngine. I looked through [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-genimutmQ&feature=player_embedded) on how to set it up but I get errors.

The errors are because the imports are not being recognized in eclipse. The imports which I am having problems with are:

```
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground; 
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.transition.FadeTransitionScene;
```

I also tried [this tutorial](http://droidcake.com/2010/12/30/how-to-create-classic-game-on-android/) which has raw code and I have the same problem.

Does anyone have a clue about what is going on, I followed the tutorial perfectly up to this point where I had to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and they were not importing.

Would appreciate any advice on this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you setup the project correctly?  It sounds as though you do not have the andengine.jar in the proper location.  Either that or you are not referencing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I did. I just opened a new project, from there downloaded the jar file as shown. Created a lib folder within the project added it in there. I then built the path and added spriteexample.java. I'll start all over again and see if I missed something. Thanks

Comment: Just thought about it but why would all the other imports for andengine work but those particular ones don't?

Comment: Still getting the same errors tried doing it a few times and now none of the imports work. Might try a different approach

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but check this site out for your multiplayer needs http://developer.casmul.com/part_home_guest/home.php. They have more features and help you implement it.
Note: I have not used it yet, but it should be interesting none the less